# Directory structure for controllers, routes, services, and models

Tags: javascript, express, model-view-controller, controller, backend

The following structure seems to be the popular suggestion (from an online search):

```
model/user.js
route/user.js
service/user.js
controller/user.js
```

What are the benefits/tradeoffs of that structure vs. the inverse?

```
user/model.js
user/route.js
user/service.js
user/controller.js
```

The latter seems to be more self-contained, and presumably easier to break out to a separate service if/when needed.

What are the tradeoffs and why might one be preferred over the other?

Comment: Good question, wondering myself. We have a bigger internal project using the former, but I think the latter would be more logical for model and controller. For view however it makes sense to keep the former structure because the directory structure aka URI reflects the type of model

Comment: Makes sense. My consideration was an api only backend. Routes and controllers are the most clear, since every route will have a controller. Controllers sometimes call only their service, but often do call out to various services (i.e. coordinating needs across different models).